# Not enough memory, setting a picture in a userform

Tags: vba, excel

In a userform I try to load a picture.

Therefore I use this code :

```
Me.Image.Picture = loadPicture("C:\MyPicture.jpeg")
```

For many pictures, it is working.
But for others (size ?) I receive a "Not enough memory" error.

Can I display a picture with an other method to avoid that ?

Comment: Is it always the same images that cause the error or is it random?

Comment: Always the same pictures yes. I have 6 pictures (~3 MB) not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved :

I only get this error when I want to load the picture if the userform is already showed.

If I prepare the picture before showing the userform, it works.

Comment: i don't think a simple loadpicture is the cause of a memory failure. You might have other buggy code around to check.

Comment: No the problem is doing that in the userform initialize sub ! I do the same before userform.show and it works

Comment: userform_initialize is BEfore the form is shown, (only loaded yet). Userform_activate is when form is shown

Comment: to change a picture (need code, use google), you can either use  `.picture = pastepicture` , Or `.picture=loadimage ("c:\img.PNG")` , or an OLE Shape (OLEObjects) on a worksheet  which has also a `.picture`property.

Comment: You are right but in my use case it was only not working because it was in initialize. Initialize is called the first time you run .show (before).

Comment: fortunately, in excel 2013, `loadpipcture` works either in initilize and activate. i can't test it in other versions of Excel...

Comment: I have also Excel 2013.